# How to add buttons in whatsapp bot using dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

[image][image: Like shown in the image. How to add buttons in whatsapp bot using dialogflow]

How to create buttons in dialogflow that should be displayed in the whatsapp bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct integration between **WhatsApp** and **Dialogflow**. You can do this with Twilio. And I don't think WhatsApp support rich response. You can send messages, audio, pdf anything that is supported currently in WhatsApp.

Dialogflow supported integration

[image]